# Limited importation using Cron, Feeds Module for Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, import, cron, feed

I want to import automatically a lot of RSS media using feeds.
Each time cron starts, the execution time doesn't reach all the queued tasks. The execution time is always between 15 and 20 seconds and it imports only 5 or 6 RSS media while there are many more planned ! Problem is that more jobs are pilling up in Queue, which doesn't empty fast enough.

I suspected a misconfiguration of cron but I didn't any parameter for execution time or maximum tasks / execution in Cron parameters.
I suspect another misconfiguration, perhaps in php.ini

We've already tried with the following parameters :

- max_execution_time = 60
- max_input_time = 60
- memory_limit = 512

But none of those parameters allowed cron to execute more tasks..

Config :

- feeds_cron, job_scheduler_cron, and queue_ui_cron runs every 15
  minutes with elysia cron
- Drupal 7.7

Answer (score 0):

You could try the dreaded `set_time_limit(0);` statement in PHP, but if editing your php.ini hasn't increased the max execution limit then it's symptomatic of a bigger problem. Really silly question but did you restart your apache/php services after editing php.ini?